# node script or npm module to check if file changed

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I'm setting up a build system using node modules and npm scripts - no gulp, etc.

I need to determine if two files are equal, before copying unnecessarily. When I used to use gulp I used [the `gulp-changed` plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-changed). I need something like that.

How could I do this in plain node?

I couldn't find an existing npm module that does this. I also checked [the `fs` module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) but didn't find anything I could use.

I need something like this: `function hasChanged(file1, file2) { /* ... */ }` but I'm not sure how to compare the files.

**UPDATE**
Using the advice given so far, this problem seems simple enough to code myself, so I'm doing that. But if you know of a node module that does this already, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: You might use fs.stat function to get file info, and compare mtime ro see of they differ. I also recommend you to lookup the sourcecode of gulp-change, its actully just a few lines of code. https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-changed?files=1

Comment: @LarsC.Magnusson Thanks - that's a good idea. I was thinking of comparing both last changed timestamp and filesize. I looked at the gulp-changed code and it's also interesting. If you add that as an answer I'll close this question.

Comment: good! I added it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use fs.stat function to get file info, and compare mtime to see if they differ. I also recommend you to lookup the sourcecode of gulp-change, its actully just a few lines of code.

https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-changed?files=1

Answer (score 1):

Do you try use [fs.watch](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener).

It is still possible to use `fs.watchFile()`, which uses stat polling, but this method is slower and less reliable.

If you want check 2 file, try using hash code of them with md5.

Comment: I don't want to watch - I want to compare two files. A hash would be very slow in a build process (thousands of files), but it's certainly an option. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need create hash when compare, just create one time and save it to reuse. This way can saving time.

Comment: True, but that's still inefficient and unnecessarily complex. @LarsC.Magnusson's answer is what I'm doing.